# Вопрос про abs и решение одной задачи на С++

Tags: c++

Решалась задача: **Шахматный король ходит по горизонтали, вертикали и диагонали, но только на 1 клетку. Даны две различные клетки шахматной доски, определите, может ли король попасть с первой клетки на вторую одним ходом.**

Решение такое:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int x1, y1, x2, y2;
cin >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;
if ((abs (x2 - x1) <= 1 && abs (y2 - y1) <= 1)) {
cout << "YES";
}
else {
cout << "NO";
}
  return 0;
}
```

Сам вопрос: почему именно где модуль <= 1, а не просто ==? Разве мы не сначала делаем число положительным, а потом уже сравниваем?

И на основе этого есть следующая задача: **Шахматный конь ходит буквой “Г” — на две клетки по вертикали в любом направлении и на одну клетку по горизонтали, или наоборот. Даны две различные клетки шахматной доски, определите, может ли конь попасть с первой клетки на вторую одним ходом.**
Решила сделать по аналогу, начертила на листочке и казалось бы поняла логику, но решение неверно:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int x1,x2,y1,y2;
    cin>>x1>>x2>>y1>>y2;
    if ((abs(x2-x1)<=2 && abs(y2-y1)<=1) ||(abs(x2-x1)<=1 && abs(y2-y1)<=2))
        cout << "YES";
    else cout << "NO";
    return 0;
}
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Нет, логику вы не поняли. По вашему коду конь может ходить на соседнюю клетку, а это не так.  Нельзя проверить тем же алгоритмом возможность ходя коня.

Comment: я вроде начертила на клетке и посчитала что там разница в координатах 2 и 1 всегда, как лучше тогда сделать?

Comment: Разница 2 и 1, а вы проверяете на 0, 1, 2 и 0, 1.

Comment: если я исправлю на == все равно ошибка не исправится, если я правильно поняла :( Я привела ниже правильный код и не смогла его преобразовать с abs, а тупо скопировать не хочется

Answer (score 2):

1. Требуемое условие для короля можно расписать как разрешение на диагональные ходы

   ```
   (abs(x2 - x1) == 1 && abs(y2 - y1) == 1) || ...
   ```

   разрешение на вертикальные ходы

   ```
   (abs(x2 - x1) == 1 && abs(y2 - y1) == 0) ||
   (abs(x2 - x1) == 0 && abs(y2 - y1) == 1) || ...
   ```

   и разрешение остаться на месте

   ```
   (abs(x2 - x1) == 0 && abs(y2 - y1) == 0)
   ```

   Как видите, везде используется строго `==`.

   Если условие задач подразумевает, что "остаться на месте" - это тоже допустимый ход, то все эти условия очевидным образом сворачиваются в просто

   ```
   (abs(x2 - x1) <= 1 && abs(y2 - y1) <= 1)
   ```

   Автор кода, очевидно, интерпретировал условие именно так, т.е. "остаться на месте" - это тоже допустимый ход.

   Такая свертка возможна потому, что область допустимых ходов короля - это полностью заполненный "квадратик".

   А вот если запретить вариант "остаться на месте", то эти условия можно свернуть в

   ```
   max(abs(x2 - x1), abs(y2 - y1)) == 1
   ```

   т.е. расстояние в Метрике Чебышева.
2. В этом случае понадобятся аналогичный набор условий, выраженных именно через `==`

   ```
   (abs(x2 - x1) == 2 && abs(y2 - y1) == 1) ||
   (abs(x2 - x1) == 1 && abs(y2 - y1) == 2)
   ```

   Но свернуть их в такой же компактный вариант с `<=` уже не получится, ибо область допустимых ходов коня не является полностью заполненным прямоугольником.

   И опять же возникает вопрос: а "остаться на месте" - это допустимый ход? Если ответ "да", то вам в ваше условие надо добавить еще условие

   ```
   ... || (abs(x2 - x1) == 0 && abd(y2 - y1) == 0) // (x2 == x1 && y2 == y1)
   ```

Comment: @VladD: Верно. Путаюсь... Исправил.

Comment: спасибо, поняла насчет 1, только не поняла насчет max. Это была бы новая переменная или функция? А насчет 2 не получается ни один из вариантов, если дополнить и исправить на ==  :( Наверно, я опять что-то упустила

Comment: int x1, y1, x2, y2, x, y;
cin >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;
x = x1 - x2;
y = y1 - y2;
if ((((x == 1) || (x == -1)) && ((y == 2) || (y == -2))) || (((x == 2) || (x == -2)) && ((y == 1) || (y == -1)))) {
cout << "YES";
} else cout << "NO";

Comment: вот нашла верное решение и не могу понять где приняла неправильно модуль :(